# Check if array element appears more than once

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

Is there a way to check an array of integers for any elements that appear more than once? Either boolean False if there are redundancies or list of offending elements would work.

Answer (score 1):

`unnest()` the array and then use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` with `count()` to filter for values that appear more than once.

```
SELECT un.n
       FROM unnest('{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}'::integer[]) un (n)
       GROUP BY un.n
       HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

To just get a Boolean you can use `EXISTS` and the above in a subquery.

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT un.n
                      FROM unnest('{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}'::integer[]) un (n)
                      GROUP BY un.n
                      HAVING count(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [intarray extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) installed, this will return `false` if you have duplicates:

```
icount(your_array) = icount(uniq(your_array))
```

If not, then I would use `unnest()` to return `false` in case of duplicates.

```
select count(unnest) = count(distinct unnest)
  from your_table
 cross join lateral unnest(your_array)
```